# Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

how to give publish_stream permission?If i trying to post on own wall,still it is saying that user is not authorised the application to do this action.I don't have any app.

Comment: You should include some code showing what you are trying to do. In general if you are using the graph API you need a token, which typically needs an app.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it. Personally I would use the Javascript SDK.
Another way is to update your Facebook App settings (using Facebook Developer App) to require users to permit Extended Permissions 'publish_stream'.

Below is code using the Javascript SDK FB.api function:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
      // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
      console.log("user is logged in and granted some permissions.")
  } else {
    // User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.
    console.log("he failed to login or something")
  }
}, {scope:'publish_stream'});
```

Inside scope: you can put a comma-separated string of permissions, if you want to ask for multiple.